# Mysterious WordPress problem -- can't figure this out

Tags: wordpress, caching

I’m having an issue with some pages on my site. It’s driving me crazy. When I’m logged into WP admin, the pages look just fine. But when I’m logged out, it doesn’t load the content and instead shows a list of all the site’s pages. And this only happens on desktop — mobile is completely fine.

I thought it might be an issue with the cache. I’ve purged the local cache and the Cloudflare cache. I’ve also tried changing themes.

The issue keeps affecting more and more pages. I’m baffled. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What I see on that page is a menu. A very large menu. I would check your menus in the admin panel and see if you have a menu that contains all of your pages and what the location is.

Comment: Have a look at your sidebar widgets. There is a lot of generated css relating to sidebar (70 instances in your css code)

Answer (score 1):

Your menu has hundreds of entries and covers the entire screen.
In Appearance -> Menu, make sure that "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu" is not ticked.

Comment: This was my thought also, now it would be wise to disable all plugins and refresh the page after each reactivation of each plugin.

Comment: On mobile view you have no menu items showing, but a large scroll of blue screen. I'm guessing this is possibly a css issue aswell. Have you made any changes to your css or your menu code?

Comment: When I look at in the inspector, it is a menu.  Is it possible that there is some plugin that is doing this? I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Has the problem started after you updated to WordPress 5.5? I've heard a lot of strange issues caused WP 5.5 because of jQuery changes.